# Which event dispatched after text selection done in StyleableTextField for iPad?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Need to know which event triggered after text selection done in Apple iPad. It works in desktop.

```
protected function txtEditor_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {   
            if(txtEditor.selectionAnchorPosition != txtEditor.selectionActivePosition){
                showNoteToolBar(event);
                txtEditor.focusEnabled = true;
                txtEditor.setFocus();
            }
        }
```

but in iPad and Andriod how to achieve through "Touch Event" ? And also i need how to hide all context menu on Spark TextArea?. Why Touch.End event is not fired after place cursor or selected text operation done on text area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In StyleableTextField it never fire any flash events after native menu box appeared(copy,paste and select all). But alternatively we can use `RichEditableText` instead.RichEditableText support TLF with all component events. RichEditableText TLF doesn't allow to open Native menu with option like(copy,paste and selectall toolbar).